# Is it possible to boot Rasberry Pi Compute Module 3+ from USB-drive?

Tags: boot, compute-module-3

Good day!
I have a device with Raspberry Pi CM3+ and Debian 10 pre-installed in eMMC.
I want to try changing the OS to something else.
I have already tried changing /boot/config.txt by adding "program_usb_boot_mode=1", but it did not work.
I do not have a debugging board for CM3+ that I could simply connect to my computer.
Do you have any advice?
I have no more ideas except for directly erasing/rewriting eMMC.

Comment: possibly some info in [this google result](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=277432)